# How to cache and synchronize data on the client

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, indexeddb, application-cache

I am going to store data on the client and synchronize them with the server database.

At the client side, I am familiar with application cache and cache storage.

How can I use application cache or cache storage for caching and synchronization?(each of them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline / Online Data Synchronization Design (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285348/offline-online-data-synchronization-design-javascript)

Comment: @Volodymyr Bilyachat your comment was helpful for me but don't refer to application cache or cache storage. thank you